# What is the efficient way to create Spark DataFrame in Scala with array type columns from another DataFrame that does not have an array column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose, I have the following the dataframe:

```
 id | col1 | col2 
-----------------
 x  |  p1  |  a1  
-----------------
 x  |  p2  |  b1
-----------------
 y  |  p2  |  b2
-----------------
 y  |  p2  |  b3
-----------------
 y  |  p3  |  c1
```

The distinct values from **col1** which are (p1, p2, p3) alone with **id** will be used as columns for the final dataframe. Here, the **id** y has two **col2** values (b2 and b3) for the same **col1** value **p2**, so, **p2** will be treated as an array type column.
Therefore, the final dataframe will be

```
  id  |   p1   |   p2   |   p3
--------------------------------
  x   |   a1   |  [b1]  |  null
--------------------------------
  y   |  null  |[b2, b3]|  c1
```

How can I achieve the second dataframe efficiently from the first dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically looking for table *pivoting*; for your case, `groupBy` `id`, `pivot` `col1` as headers, and aggregate `col2` as list using `collect_list` function:

```
df.groupBy("id").pivot("col1").agg(collect_list("col2")).show
+---+----+--------+----+
| id|  p1|      p2|  p3|
+---+----+--------+----+
|  x|[a1]|    [b1]|  []|
|  y|  []|[b2, b3]|[c1]|
+---+----+--------+----+
```

If it's guaranteed that there's at most one value in `p1` and `p3` for each `id`, you can convert those columns to String type by `getting` the first item of the array:

```
df.groupBy("id").pivot("col1").agg(collect_list("col2"))
  .withColumn("p1", $"p1"(0)).withColumn("p3", $"p3"(0))
  .show
+---+----+--------+----+
| id|  p1|      p2|  p3|
+---+----+--------+----+
|  x|  a1|    [b1]|null|
|  y|null|[b2, b3]|  c1|
+---+----+--------+----+
```

If you need to convert the column types dynamically, i.e. only use array type column types when you have to:

```
// get array Type columns
val arrayColumns = df.groupBy("id", "col1").agg(count("*").as("N"))
    .where($"N" > 1).select("col1").distinct.collect.map(row => row.getString(0))
// arrayColumns: Array[String] = Array(p2)

// aggregate / pivot data frame
val aggDf = df.groupBy("id").pivot("col1").agg(collect_list("col2"))
// aggDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, p1: array<string> ... 2 more fields]

// get string columns
val stringColumns = aggDf.columns.filter(x => x != "id" && !arrayColumns.contains(x))

// use foldLeft on string columns to convert the columns to string type
stringColumns.foldLeft(aggDf)((df, x) => df.withColumn(x, col(x)(0))).show
+---+----+--------+----+
| id|  p1|      p2|  p3|
+---+----+--------+----+
|  x|  a1|    [b1]|null|
|  y|null|[b2, b3]|  c1|
+---+----+--------+----+
```

Comment: I want p1 and p3 to be string type but not an array type.

Comment: I'm not really sure if that makes a lot of sense unless you are sure, there are at most one value in `p1` and `p3` for each `id`. In which case, you can extract the first element from `p1` and `p3`. `df.groupBy("id").pivot("col1").agg(collect_list("col2")).withColumn("p1", $"p1"(0)).withColumn("p3", $"p3"(0)).show` should give what you need.

Comment: The thing is the distinct values from *col1* are not fixed, they can be any number of elements.

Comment: In that case I would keep all the pivoted columns as Array Type instead of String type. At the end of day, if you are not even sure how many columns you have, how do you know what type they should be in?

Comment: I can find the names of the Array Type columns from the first dataframe using **SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM (SELECT id, col1, COUNT (*) AS rowCount FROM df GROUP BY id , col1 HAVING rowCount > 1**. The main problem is that creating the final dataframe dynamically using the name of Array Type columns.

Comment: Can you share the first data frame and how you can decide the Array Type columns? If you can collect the Array type column names, you can use the reduce function or a simple for loop to manipulate the column types.

Comment: Suppose, I got the Array Type columns as Array[String] = [p2,p4,....]. Can you provide a code snippet that how can I apply the reduce function or a simple for loop to manipulate the column types?

Comment: Updated the answer. You can use foldLeft on the arrays to create the expression to transform the data frame.